# Kotlin and Java code show mistakes when I open a flutter project in Android Studio

Tags: flutter

[image]

As the picture show above, when I open a fltter project in Android Studio, **all Java and Kotlin files show errors**, but flutter run is work normally, how do I do with this problem?

Comment: don't open it. Or restart Android Studio. I think it happens because you are on a Flutter project.

Comment: Agreed, but restart was doesn't work, may be this is because the project was not opened as an Android or Java project, it's okay if it's normal, I was just worried about whether I made a mistake or not, may be there is another way to code both flutter and kotlin at the same time, thanks

Comment: I generally open android folder under a flutter project as a separate project in Android Studio, and I open ios folder with xcode. It would be nice to have the flutter project opened and at least kotlin/java indexing properly, but I haven't found a way to make that work yet. Kinda makes sense because flutter doesn't really call methods in the native code directly, native code and flutter only communicate via MethodChannel/BasicMessageChannel

Answer (score 0):

Just restart the IDE and the errors should disappear (worked for me).
To restart Android Studio click on file > Restart IDE...